# Spring Batch Job Failed with Insert command got aborted

Tags: spring-batch, amazon-redshift

I am using spring batch framework to execute jobs which takes data from file and try to insert into redshift table.

There are few instance where job failed with

> exitDescription=org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO dfp_zone( name, keyname, siteid, status, dfpzoneid,lastupdatedat,createdat,updatedat) SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,getdate(),getdate() WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dfp_zone WHERE dfpzoneid = ?) ]; SQL state [XX000]; error code [0]; Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO dfp_zone( name, keyname, siteid, status, dfpzoneid,lastupdatedat,createdat,updatedat) SELECT 'edward_jones_sponsored_post.bottom', 'edward_jones_sponsored_post.bottom', '87', 'ACTIVE', '267083899','2016-08-29 09:18:28.000000 +00:00',getdate(),getdate() WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dfp_zone WHERE dfpzoneid = '267083899') was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause

When I take out individual command and try to execute it separately it executes without any issue.

One possible reason could be some lock might present at the time the command is being executed through job.

But Can I somehow get the exact reason for failure.

Please help!!

Comment: You can catch this exception with a listener and call `getNextException()` to see real error (or trace with an SQL monitor)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for Commenting, I added jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().toString() code to JobExecutionListener class ... But even if I pring all exception, it says callGetNextException to see the cause.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your listener and call getNextException(); printing exception is not suffice